# Search through tar files for a pattern and print the full path of what's found

Tags: linux, find, tar

I have directory tree with many tar files. Each tar file contains many other files. I want to search through all the tar files for a given pattern, and print **the full path** of any files within a tar that are found.

I got this far:
`find . -type f -name '*.tar' -exec tar tf {} \; | egrep '<pattern>'`

Now my problem is that the above command only prints the name of the file within the tar that it finds. Ie, the output of the above is:
`pattern.jpg
foundMe.txt`

I would like the output to contain also the full path and the tar name where the file was found. How would I do this?

Thank you!

Comment: What is your pattern -- it is capturing only the filiename?  For me `find` returns the full path relative to whence I'm executing the command by default.

Comment: Yes, find does do that, but then -exec tar tf only returns the name of the file within the tar archive

Comment: Have you tried `execdir`?  See [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108216/find-with-execdir).

Comment: that doesn't help, tar tf still only outputs the name of the file, I need to combine the tar file path from <find> command with result of <tar tf | egrep 'pattern'>

Answer (score 0):

Of course, lost the plot somewhere along the line `:$`

I had a similar problem with jar files, looking for java classes. Used to do something like this: capture the output of each `tar tf|grep <pattern>` then look see if the output contains a value - if so, print name (`$f`) and value (`$p`):

```
find . -name '*.tar' -type f|while read f; do p="$(tar tf $f|egrep <pattern>)"; [ -n "$p" ] && echo -e "$f\n$p" ; p=""; done
```

Switched the order of find arguments - cheaper to look at file name before file type.

Comment: I am searching for files within tar archives, this doesn't help